# update of property failing -- JavaScript 'this' not pointing to the right object

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, prototype

I have a Person constructor that will get or set a person's first, last, and full names.

```
var Person = function(firstAndLast) {
    var self = this;
    this.getFirstName = function(){
      var first = self.firstName || (function(){
        return firstAndLast.split(' ')[0];

      })();
      return first;
    };
    this.getLastName = function(){
      var last = self.lastName || (function(){
        return firstAndLast.split(' ')[1];

      })();
      return last;
    };
    this.getFullName = function(){
      var full = self.fullName || (function(){
        var first = firstAndLast.split(' ')[0];
        var last = firstAndLast.split(' ')[1];
        return first + " " + last;
      })();
      return full;
    };
    this.setFirstName = function(first){
      self.firstName = first;
      console.log('first name is now: ' + self.firstName);
    };
    this.setLastName = function(last){
      self.lastName = last;
      console.log('last name is now: ' + self.lastName);
    };
    this.setFullName = function(firstAndLast){
      self.fullName = firstAndLast;
      console.log('full name is now: ' + self.fullName);
    };
};
```

Get methods work as expected...

```
var claude = new Person('Claude Shannon');
claude.getFullName();
```

But why doesn't the following work?

```
claude.setFirstName('james');
claude.getFullName();  //  "Claude Shannon"
```

(Obviously I was expecting "James Shannon

Comment: You are mixing `this` and `self` all over the place. You might want to streamline your logic.

Comment: @FabianKlötzl  Sorry, only noticed that after post.  I tried to fix it, but it seems that I'm still not getting the behavior I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you never actually return the new full name (made up of the two properties set by `setFirstName` and `setLastName`). You return the one from the constructor.

```
this.getFullName = function(){
  var full = this.fullName || (function(){
    var first = firstAndLast.split(' ')[0];
    var last = firstAndLast.split(' ')[1];
    return first + " " + last;
  })();
  return full;
};
```

vs.

```
this.getFullName = function(){
  return this.getFirstName() + " " + this.getLastName()
};
```

```js
var Person = function(firstAndLast) {
    var self = this;
    this.getFirstName = function(){
      var first = this.firstName || (function(){
        return firstAndLast.split(' ')[0];

      })();
      return first;
    };
    this.getLastName = function(){
      var last = this.lastName || (function(){
        return firstAndLast.split(' ')[1];

      })();
      return last;
    };
    this.getFullName = function(){
      return this.getFirstName() + " " + this.getLastName()
    };
    this.setFirstName = function(first){
      self.firstName = first;
      console.log('first name is now: ' + self.firstName);
    };
    this.setLastName = function(last){
      self.lastName = last;
      console.log('last name is now: ' + self.lastName);
    };
    this.setFullName = function(firstAndLast){
      self.fullName = firstAndLast;
      console.log('full name is now: ' + self.fullName);
    };
};

var claude = new Person('Claude Shannon');
console.log(claude.getFullName());

claude.setFirstName('James');
console.log(claude.getFullName()); //  "Claude Shannon"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice to put all the methods into the prototype and just use this everywhere.

But the issue is that getFullName() looks at the this.fullName property.
Since you used setFirstName(), which only sets this.firstName to James, the getFullName keeps looking back to the parameter used in the constructor, namely 'Claude Shannon', because this.fullName is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading full name from the initial argument passed to the constructor - which never updates. You need to read from properties. When getting first or last name, you do read from dynamic properties, but for full name, you're always reading from that initial constructor arg.

Furthermore, there is no reason to write to `self` - `this` is fine.

I made a few other changes. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5j1cLkL/).

```
var Person = function(first, last) {
    //var self = this; <-- unnecessary
    this.getFirstName = function(){
      var first = this.firstName || (function(){
        return firstAndLast.split(' ')[0];

      })();
      return first;
    };
    this.getLastName = function(){
      var last = this.lastName || (function(){
        return firstAndLast.split(' ')[1];

      })();
      return last;
    };
    this.getFullName = function(){
      //much simpler than before - just concatenate properties
      return this.firstName+' '+this.lastName;
    };
    this.setFirstName = function(first){
      this.firstName = first;
      alert('first name is now: ' + this.firstName);
    };
    this.setLastName = function(last){
      this.lastName = last;
      console.log('last name is now: ' + this.lastName);
    };
    this.setFullName = function(firstAndLast){
      this.fullName = firstAndLast;
      console.log('full name is now: ' + this.fullName);
    };
    this.setFirstName(first); //set initial first name passed to construc
    this.setLastName(last);   //" " last " " " "
};
```

var claude = new Person('Claude', 'Shannon'); //note, two separate args
claude.setFirstName('James');
alert(claude.getFullName());  //  "James Shannon"

Comment: I'm given a certain type of data to work with, I don't have the option of having two arguments

Answer (score 0):

In your getFullName function, you are not checking for first Name. You are only checking if the fullname is there or not. Even though you correct your contexts in the code still you will face the issue because the logic.

```
this.getFullName = function(){
  var full = this.fullName || (function(){
    var first = firstAndLast.split(' ')[0];
    var last = firstAndLast.split(' ')[1];
    return first + " " + last;
  })();
  return full;
};
```